# File access error when deleting

Tags: c#, .net, file-io

The purpose of my code here is to monitor a folder for xml files. If a file is placed in the folder, it will be read, converted to byte[], sent over a socket to a server, and deleted.

This only works if a file that hasn't been previously sent, gets placed in the folder.

Example: I send 1.xml, everything works fine and file gets deleted.
         I paste 1.xml in to the folder.
         File gets read, but upon deleting, throws an exception (used by another
         process).

If I wait long enough or alternate file names, it will work just fine.
I could add a delay (tested to work with at least 3 seconds) but that defeats the purpose of my program.

I wrote this same code in Python and it works fine so I'm stumped.
See my code below. Thanks for any help!

```
string[] files;
while (sending)
{
    files = Directory.GetFiles(Events_Directory, "*.xml");                    
    foreach(string file in files)
    {
        Message = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Regex.Replace(
                            File.ReadAllText(file), @"[\r\n\t ]+", ""));
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        Sock.Send(Message);
        File.Delete(file);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I was wrong about where the exception occurred. It was actually after trying to read the file the 2nd go around.
I noticed that if thread that this code is running in was terminated and "re"started, everything went fine. So I added a workaround to put the thread itself in a loop, rather than the method of the thread.

```
        while (sending)
    {
                Thread EventSenderThread = new Thread(() =>
                    Communications.EventSender(Event_Directory));
                EventSenderThread.Start();
                while (EventSenderThread.IsAlive)
                { System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents(); }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a StreamReader and explicitly close the stream after reading.

```
string[] files;
while (sending)
{
    files = Directory.GetFiles(Events_Directory, "*.xml");
    foreach (string file in files)
    {
        StreamReader IN = new StreamReader(file);
        string allText = IN.ReadToEnd();
        IN.Close();
        Message = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Regex.Replace(
                            allText, @"[\r\n\t ]+", ""));
        Sock.Send(Message);
        File.Delete(file);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried that. Actually, I was using StreamReader initially but then went to File.ReadAllText to avoid any open/close errors.
When stepping through the code, the exception doesn't get thrown until the second time the file gets deleted.

Comment: What do you mean by the second time a file is deleted? I only see 1 call for deletion.

Comment: It's in a loop. Assume sending = True.

So it monitors that folder "Events_Directory" for xml files as long as sending is True (user controlled).

If I paste a file, "1.xml" in to the folder, it does everything just fine, including deleting. Now, while still in that loop, if I paste the same file "1.xml", I get the exception once I reach the call for deletion, the second time.

I hope that explains it better.

Comment: So you're saying that files = Directory.GetFiles(Events_Directory, "*.xml"); gives you files that were already deleted?

Comment: @Brrom, I was wrong about where the exception occurred. It wasn't during deletion but reading the second (newly pasted in to the directory) file. I'm assuming it's a speed issue. 
Even though the program recognizes a new file, and then tries to open the file for reading, the file seemed to not exist. 
I fixed it though. See my answer above.
Thanks for your help!